# Error submitting COMPSs application to a Cluster

Tags: hpc, compss, pycompss

I am getting an error when submitting a COMPSs application at a cluster

I execute this

```
$ enqueue_compss --lang=python /home/bsc21/bsc21863/simple.py 3
```

And receive this error,

```
/gpfs/apps/MN3/COMPSs/1.4/Runtime/scripts/user/../queues/lsf/submit.sh: 
line 1: ﻿#!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Queue:           default
Reservation  disabled
Num Nodes:       2
Num Switches:    0
Job dependency:  None
Exec-Time:       00:10
Network:         ethernet
Node memory:     disabled
Tasks per Node:  16
Tasks in Master: 0
Master Port:     43306
Master WD:       .
Worker WD:       scratch
Library Path:    .
Classpath:       .
COMM:            integratedtoolkit.nio.master.NIOAdaptor
To COMPSs:       --lang=python /home/bsc21/bsc21863/simple.py 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submission seems correct. Ignore the print of log  `line 1: ﻿#!/bin/bash: No such file or directory`. I do not know why it is appearing, but it doesn't stop the submission. Have you check if there was a job submitted after the command execution or some .out or .err files have been appeared later?

Comment: I didn't realize it was submitting the job anyway. It appears to be working fine. Thank you